# Dissolving all overlapping, intersecting, touching polygons on single layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, merge, overlapping-features, dissolve

I'm quite new to Qgis and have a problem which is easy to solve, I think. I've done research for hours but did not succeed.

I have a data set which contains thousands of polygons **in one layer**.
What I want to do:
Dissolve all polygons which overlap, intersect or touch with others. This means that there should not be any borders between overlapping, intersecting or touching polygons anymore. I don't have any helping attributes to achieve this.

Finally, I would like to export a new .shp file of the new data set.

I tried "dissolve all" but this makes just one big polygon, which I don't want. As a first step i thought to solve it with "Intersect...". But this works just with two layers. With the advanced digitizing tools I would have to select all of them manually to "merge selected features".

I'm using Qgis version 2.14.15

[image]

Comment: What about dissolving all and then split it in multi part? You have a tool for that in the advanced editing tools.

Answer (score 2):

Try dissolving all and then split it in multi part. You have a tool for that in the advanced editing tools.

Edit: Split in single part!!!

Comment: Thank you very much Noe. The solution was, as you suggested, to dissolve all but then split in **single** parts lead to the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to single part instead of multi part. It was a lapse!