# QGIS - Set display order of polygon features in the same layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table, display

in QGIS I have a polygon layer with overlapping features. While this is not ideal (and I am currently changing this), I am wondering whether I can in any way affect the order of the features displayed. My smaller feature is in the background, so I can´t see it (and have a harder time editing it, though I am solving this by making the overlapping layer transparent).

I have tried sorting the attribute table differently, this does not affect the order of display of the features in my layer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like this answers your question. gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183048/changing-feature-draw-order-in-qgis

Comment: The order of the visualisation of the features is connected with features ID. 
Give a look at this similar question and its answer The order of the visualisation of the features is connected with features ID. 
Give a look at this similar question and its answer 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353889/qgis-make-selected-hidden-objects-visible/353906#353906

Answer (score 0):

How about having the overlapping features in a different layer so that you can just arrange them in the layers panel? I think the following workflow might work (although I haven't tried it).

1. First dissolve the overlapping small polygons into the background polygon (like in this answer: [Dissolving all overlapping, intersecting, touching polygons on single layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248305/dissolving-all-overlapping-intersecting-touching-polygons-on-single-layer-usin/248320))
2. Select the dissolved features from a duplicate of the original layer and delete them.
3. Run difference between the original layer and the duplicate of the original layer (the one with the dissolved features removed)
4. Now you have 1 layer with the big polygons and 1 layer with the overlapping small polygons and you can style them different and change the order in the layers panel.

Comment: Seems that the comments to your question above do the job without too much work!

Comment: Thanks but I do know how to solve the problem by working around it, I was just wondering whether there actually is a possibility to control the drawing order of different features - as pointed out by others, there is already an answer in a different question.